# Import attachemtns using csv in prestashop 1.7

Tags: import, prestashop

I want to import/update attachments to already added products via CSV file
(Product ID / Attachment Filename), however i can't import it via admin panel.

I have tried PRESTASHOP STORE MANAGER which only import files from desktop to host (Products files (2GB) are located in host root).

Is there any way to handle the issue without uploading files from desktop.

Thanks.

Comment: Why you can't import it via admin panel, witch error you have when you try to import.

Comment: Import attachments throw admin panel not available